# How to display date in Fifteenth JUNE, 2016 format in sql

Tags: sql, formatting, oracle10g

I want to fetch data from my database table and I want to display it in Fifteenth JUNE, 2016 Format

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple!

```
select to_char(date'2016-06-15', 'fmDdspth MONTH, YYYY') from dual;

Fifteenth JUNE, 2016
```

Explaining the date format string:

- `fm` = remove filler characters (extra spaces are removed)
- `Ddsp` = Day of the month, spelled out in words, in Initcap
- `th` = add the "th", "nd" or "st" number suffix
- `MONTH` = Month name, in uppercase
- `YYYY` = Century and Year

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm having not oracle 10g, so I tested on 11g, where it runs perfectly. Give a shot at your end and comment what happens.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DateValue, 'Ddspth')||' '||TO_CHAR(DateValue, 'fmMONTH')||' , '|| TO_CHAR(DateValue, 'YYYY') FROM TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should implement your own function or case statement, because Oracle doesn't have this functionality.
See [TO_CHAR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm#i1009324) and [Datetime format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) for details.